# Multiple select on the edit form

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following form:

[image]

This is the edit form.

As you can see I have a multiple select. I need to bind the values from the server to the select. 
Here is structure of my objects from the server.
1) All elements for the multiple select:

[image]

2) Particular objects, that I want to see selected. As you can see, there's an additional field called 'pivot'.

[image]

As a result, I would like to see the following when I open my form:
[image]

I have tried something like this, but without success:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="bk">Связанные бк</label>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="bk" v-model="formFields.applicationBk" multiple>
    <option v-for="bk in allBk" v-if="applicationBk.find(x => x.id === bk.id) 'selected'" >
        {{ bk.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Here is full js code:

```
<script>
import { EventBus } from '../../app';

export default {
    name: "ApplicationEdit",
    props: ['applicationId', 'name', 'offer', 'bundleId', 'isBlackMode', 'applicationBk', 'allBk'],
    mounted: function(){
        console.log(this.applicationBk)

    },
    methods:{
        submit: function (e) {
            window.axios.post('/application/edit/' + this.applicationId, this.formFields)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('Сохранил!');
                    $('#applicationEdit' + this.applicationId).modal('hide');

                    EventBus.$emit('reloadApplicationsTable');
                }).catch(err => {
                if(err.response.status === 422){
                    this.errors = err.response.data.errors || [];
                }
                //console.error('Ошибка сохранения приложения. Описание: ');
                console.error(err)
            });
        }
    },
    data(){
        return {
            formFields: {
                applicationId: this.applicationId,
                applicationBk: this.applicationBk,
                name: this.name,
                offer: this.offer,
                bundle_id: this.bundleId,
                giraffe: this.isBlackMode,
                bk: this.applicationBk,
            },
            errors: []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, partly because you've chosen dfjgklsld as input data, and partly because your example screenshots are in a foreign language.

Comment: I think this package can to solve my task https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using your loop as you have but using v-model to an array of the selected values.  Here is vue's example of this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: Can't you bind :selected and then use the conditions that you are already using?